# How can i avoid duplicate BCP-47 language Code from AVSpeechSynthesisVoice: speechVoices()?

Tags: ios, swift, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis, avspeechsynthesizer

I am working on a text-to-speech feature in an iOS app which displays a list of available speech voices from `AVSpeechSynthesisVoice: speechVoices()`. Sometimes, the list shows duplicates (i am displaying language names per locale). The reason I found for this behavior is **Enhanced** quality for voices in addition to **Default**. So, if **Enhanced** speech voice is installed on the user's device this list will show duplicate language codes e.g. For English, if Samantha(Enhanced) is downloaded in addition to Samantha(Default). I do not know but i observed that my phone automatically installs Enhanced voice sometimes.

I just want to show the Default voices hence list items should be unique.

Can somebody suggest me the cleaner and nicest way to do this ?

Comment: But Should i show user the option to choose between Default and Enhanced speech voices, if available on user's device ? Is there any kind of Apple standard to do so ?

Comment: I was able to achieve it by filtering(if condition) the objects from AVSpeechSynthesisVoice: speechVoices by speech voice quality property. But this property is only available from iOS 9.0 and higher. for lower versions i think i need to write some logic. Any suggestions other than this ?